# Хочу понять как работает алгоритм по вычислению цифрового корня

Tags: c#, алгоритм, функции, системы-счисления

```
public int DigitalRoot(long n) => (int) (1 + (n - 1) % 9); 

public int DigitalRoot(long n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        sum += n % 10;
        n/= 10;
    }
    if (sum > 9)  return (int)DigitalRoot(sum); else return (int)sum;          
}
```

Есть две функции, выдающие абсолютно одинаковый результат для натуральных чисел. Однако первая написана не мной и очень хотелось бы понять почему это так работает?

Comment: Есть прекрасный ответ а эту тему. Скажу честно, я его нагуглил. https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18286. Если очень кратко: из-за того, что остаток от деления степеней десятки (10, 100, 1000, …) на 9 всегда равен единице, сумма цифр числа и само число при делении на 9 дают один и тот же остаток. На этом рассуждения и строятся.